# @ViewChild returns undefined

Tags: angular, viewchild

For some reason my @ViewChild in my Angular 5 App does not work.
I have defined it like this in my component:

**case-detail.component.html:**

```html
<div class="inner-tab-content" #innerTabContent>
    <!-- // more content here -->
</div>
```

I have implemented `@ViewChild` in my controller (above the constructor) like this:

**case-detail.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('innerTabContent') tabContentElement: ElementRef;
```

And I want to access it here in the component:
**case-detail.component.ts**

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("scroll top: " + this.tabContentElement.nativeElement);
}
```

I've implemented the `AfterViewInit` interface. ngAfterViewInit() is called correctly. However, `this.tabContentElement` is always `undefined`.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show us how have you implemented @ViewChild?

Comment: Sure, just updated my answer :)

Comment: if you are using `#innerTabContent` you will have the elementRef directly and not `nativeElement`. `console.log(this.tabContentElement)` you will get the HTML element

Comment: @Aravind That does not work either. this.tabContentElement is undefined unfortunately.

Comment: @dave0688 Is it possible that the block where your #innerTabContent element is defined is in some `*ngIf` or other conditional template that is not rendered at the time of afterviewinit ?

Comment: Can you try putting the read property? 
@ViewChild('innerTabContent', {read: ElementRef}) tabContentElement: ElementRef;

Comment: @Pac0 Good guess. Yes, that's the case! :) Just tried it with a timeout of 5 seconds and it works. Thanks a lot :) Please write an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ViewChild()` works fine on latest plunker Angular version with the scenario you describe.

Demonstration in this plunker : <strike>https://plnkr.co
/edit/KzWnkE5Hvp7NUow6YAxy</strike>

EDIT: Here is a replacement StackBlitz for the above Plunker: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzaglm

component :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.testView); // correctly outputs the element in console, not undefined
}
```

- Check that ElementRef and ViewChild are correctly imported from '@angular/core'
- **Your element might simply not be there at the time of AfterViewInit (in case there is a `*ngIf`, for instance.** (seems the case as per your comments)

In the latter case, you can use a wrapper element and `ViewChildren` , that emits some event when a new child element is added - more info on documentation here : https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

note that there might be some issue with native `div` as per this question :  [@ViewChildren does not get updated with dynamically added DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510444/viewchildren-does-not-get-updated-with-dynamically-added-dom-elements) , but this can be worked around by using a new component that wraps your div, for instance.

### EDIT

Or you can also use a timeout to wait for the component to be rendered. I must say that I find this solution 'dirty', but glad it works for you :)

Comment: to rely on timeout is a really bad idea.

Comment: Why does *ngIf cause the problem with elements not appearing AfterViewInigt?

Comment: @IcedDante Not sure if I understood your actual question properly, but if the condition is _falsy_ in `*ngIf="condition"`, then the actual element won't be present in the DOM at all. So you can't select it. That's an expected behavior of Angular.

Comment: oh ok... yes I thought because you said the element "might... not be there at the time" that it would asynchronously appear later for some reason.

Comment: If 'viewChild' element is with *ngIf block, it will return undefined only. In this case, need to replace *ngIf with [style.display]="conditionToDisplay > 0 ? 'block' : 'none'" .

Answer (score 20):

However, even if you access to the child component in the `AfterViewInit`, sometimes the `@ViewChild` was still returning `null`. The problem can be caused by the `*ngIf` or other directive.

The solution is to use the `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` and subscribe the `changes` subscription that is executed when the component is ready.

For example, if in the parent component `ParentComponent` you want to access the child component `MyComponent`.

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component';

export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
  //other code emitted for clarity

  @ViewChildren(MyComponent) childrenComponent: QueryList<MyComponent>;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
    this.childrenComponent.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList<MyComponent>) =>
    {
      // Now you can access to the child component
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: But what do you do if this.childrenComponent is still undefined by time you reach ngAfterViewInit -- there's nothing to subscribe to :(

Comment: I think that you are missing something on your code, because `this.childrenComponent` is the reference of the template component. If you put your code on "CodeSandbox" I can try to help you.

Answer (score 10):

To get this to work consistently in my case, I replaced all occurrences of

```
*ngIf="check"
```

with

```
[style.display]="check ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

Otherwise the ViewChild components that didn't exist when my view first loaded would potentially remain undefined.

Comment: wont work for dynamicaly added controls, like table row added on button click

Comment: *ngIf was the issue in my case .... thanks Langford, this has worked out for me!

Answer (score 6):

A different answer to this question would be sometimes, The child component is still not rendered, when you access it. For me it was due to an *ngIf so that child component is still not there. For an example,

```
<div *ngIf="check">
   <app-child-item></app-child-item>
</div>
```

And in your parent .ts file you try to access childItem while check is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Using timeout and setting static to false worked for me.

```
@ViewChild(GoogleMapComponent) _GoogleMap: GoogleMapComponent; //Static is false
        
//Now use setTimeout inside ngOnInit
ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._GoogleMap.$mapReady.subscribe((map) => {
        this.map = map;
        marker.setMap(map);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Using setTimeount is a dirty fix, it would be better to look at the Angular lifecycle and use ngAfterViewInit instead.

Comment: Tried, it's not working with ngAfterViewInit().

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321568/viewchild-returns-undefined#comment95239693_48322136) where `@ViewChildren` still has a chance of being undefined during `ngAfterViewInit`. I've found another solution that avoids any race conditions or timers.

Change your `@ViewChild` variable to a `set` function, and store the `ElementRef` in a separate variable.

```
@ViewChild('innerTabContent')
set tabContentElement(element: ElementRef) {
  this._tabContentElement = element;
  console.log("scroll top: " + this.element.nativeElement);
  // anything else to execute once, when view child is found
}
```