# MatSort is undefined - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I'm trying to implement a Material table in my angular application. Pagination and Filter are working fine, but i'm not able to sort my table. My reference to MatSort is undefined.

I did import it in AppModule:

```
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,MatPaginatorModule,MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';

...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [   
     MatSortModule,
     MatTableModule,
     MatPaginatorModule,
     MatInputModule,
     ...
   ]
  })
```

Here is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
...
import {MatTableDataSource,MatSort,MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';
...
export class MyClass inplements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort:MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator:MatPaginator;
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.fake_data);
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
  }
 ...
}
```

And here is my component HTML:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="ready" class="width-80">
   <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-table #table class = "mat-elevation-z8 animate" matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" display:flex>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="fake_name">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="columnTitle"><b>{{fake_label.name}}</b></mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let fake;" class="cellContent">{{fake.name}}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="fakeColumns"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: fakeColumns" class="animate"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,15,20,25,50,100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of  declaring this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; in ngAfterViewInit() try to call it in ngOnInit()

Comment: I did, it keeps undefined, i tryied ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit and an external function. none of them worked

Answer (score 20):

Issue can be fixed adding in apps.module.ts:

```
import { MatPaginatorModule,MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and:

```
imports: [
    ....
    MatPaginatorModule,        
    MatSortModule
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I've found an answer [on a Angular's issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8041#issuecomment-417638817).

In my particular case (and that guy's case on github), it was solved removing the `*ngIf` on the `mat-table` tag. I'm not sure but maybe that `<mat-form-field *ngIf="ready" class="width-80">` is causing some trouble.

Comment: Using Angular 14 and Material 14, and this is still the case. Removed the *ngIf and sorting works again.

Answer (score 5):

With Angular 8 and Material 6.4.1 if you waiting to receive a data from a service the simplest and best way to fix it just set the **static: false** instead of true, like this:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { **static: false** }) sort: MatSort;
```

In my case is an ngOnChanges call for data.

FYI: same for MatPaginator.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of `*ngIf="ready"`. If we are setting this to `ready` from parent component, then place `datasource.sort` on `ngOnChanges` as this is the first life-cycle hook that gets called:

```js
ngOnChanges(){ this.datasource.sort = sort; this.datasource.paginator = paginator; }
```

Alternatively, if you are changing `ready` in same component, place `datasource.sort` before you are setting ready `false`:

```js
ngOnInit(){ this.datasource.sort = sort; this.datasource.paginator = paginator; this.ready=false; }
```

And, finally, initialize your `datasource` with some default value so `this.datasource` will not be null or undefined.

```js
datasource=new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
mat-sort-header="FIELDNAME"
```

as my columns contain "transformed" data.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using two MatTables and for the second one, I was doing pagination and sorting. By mistake I wrote matSort for the first table also.
So, in component file, it was searching for sort and paginator of first table and I was defining it for second table.